# How could I get ModelAndView object in js by using for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jakarta-ee

I want to ask, how could I get ModelAndView object's value in js by using for loop?

In controller, I wrote this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="SearchCourse.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchCourse() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/student/SearchCourse");
    model.addObject("schoolList", schoolService.listSchool());
    return model;
}
```

In js, if I wrote:

```
${
    schoolList.get(0).getSchoolname()
}
```

Then, I can get the result.

However, if I wrote a for loop:

```
var schoolList = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < "${schoolList.size()}"; i++) {
    alert("${schoolList.get("+i+").getSchoolname()}"); //error
}
```

Then, I will get an error.
I know I can't get write code like the above because i misuse the syntax.
But, how can I get the schoolList in js by using ModelAndView?

Answer (score 1):

The first expression is not JavaScript, it is jstl expression.
If you want access to the model in JavaScript you either need to assign values to javascript variables or return JSON objects to your requests.
To assign values to javascript array, you should do something like this:

```
<script>
 var schoolList=new Array();
  <c:forEach items="schoolList" var="school">
      schoolList[]=${school.schoolname};
   </c:forEach>

</script>
```

Notice, that there is a mix of javascript and jstl in this code. This is a sample code, there might be errors.

Check the answers to the questions below which were similar to yours.

[How to transfer java array to javaScript array using jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516565/how-to-transfer-java-array-to-javascript-array-using-jsp)

[How to pass array from java to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931350/how-to-pass-array-from-java-to-javascript)

[Converting a Java ArrayList of strings to a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array)

Comment: user3362816 made suggestions with the similar questions

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @jny ! I have figured it out by myself.
We can simply use the code below to get the list and iterate the list.

```
<script>
var schoolList=${schoolList}
for(var i=0;i<schoolList.length;i++) {
  alert(schoolList[i].schoolname);
}
</script>
```